# Codespaces (online.visualstudio.com) - Cannot find module 'tslint/lib/tsLintCli.js'

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, codespaces

I am developing on Codespaces (online.visualstudio.com) but got an error as below. Note: I've removed node_modules and *npm install* again a few time but doesn't resolve...also it worked OK in my local environment...my problem is I dont know how to fix it on Codespaces. Does everyone help me an advice?

node: v12.16.3
npm: 6.14.4
Running Linter

- failed: Error: Cannot find module 'tslint/lib/tsLintCli.js'
  Require stack:
- /home/codespace/workspace/
- /home/codespace/workspace